# jQuery Tools - Can you manually set the url in the history plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I am using the jquery tools history plugin to add history functionality page. I am using this code

```
$("a.links_with_history").history(function(event, hash) {

});
```

Is there a way to manually set the url here instead of getting the value from the href attribute of the anchor tag?

EDIT: For the purposes of this question, assume that we are going to use jQuery tools and not another plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I'd use a similar plugin: [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js/).

Then, what you need is a pushState. This is what it says in the [read me](https://github.com/balupton/history.js/blob/master/README.md):

> ```
> History.pushState(data,title,url)
> ```
>
> *Pushes a new state to the browser; data can be null or an object, title can be null or a string, url must be a string*

Comment: I try to minimize the number of plugins so I am afraid using another is not an option

Comment: @arvinsim I don't understand the problem. You just replace the history plugin with the history.js one.